# Modal on Modal in Materialize

Tags: angularjs, typescript, materialize

I have modal pop up and in that modal popup i want to have one more modal popup(smaller modal).My code is as follows

Click event for 1st modal

```
<!-- Modal Trigger -->
  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>
```

My Modal

```
 <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="modal2" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat modal-trigger">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I want to show my 2nd popup modal after clicking on Agree button my 2nd modal is as follows.

```
<!-- Modal Structure -->
      <div id="modal2" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <p>Thank you</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

When i open my 1st pop up i am unable to open 2nd popup. How can i achive popup modal on popup modal using materialize UI?

Comment: Showing more than one popover/overlay is a bad UX design, this always confuses the user. what you can do is to hide popover1 before showing popover2  & vice versa.

Comment: Thanks dreamweiver for the alternative options.

Comment: Hey @bob, if you have created a final solution, then why dont you post it here and close this question :)